# vb.net, Create object that refers to another object crashes project

Tags: vb.net

I'm at a loss why this is not working and other questions and answers here has not lead me to an answer.

I have a simple project with 2 listboxes. One is named lList and the other is named lListH.

The below works:

```vb
function MyFunction (byval lList as listbox, byval lListH as listbox)
    lList.Items.Add("Visible list")
    lListH.Items.Add("Hidden List")

end Function
```

Whereas the below is what I'd like to use, but it doesn't work:

```vb
function MyFunction (byval lList as listbox)
    Dim sControlName = lList.Name & "H"
    Debug.Print(sControlName)  'Outputs lListH as expected

    Dim lListH As ListBox = CType(Me.Controls(sControlName), ListBox)

    lList.Items.Add("Visible list")
    lListH.Items.Add("Hidden List") 'error on this line: System.NullReferenceException, 0x80004003

end Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the `ListBox` is not directly on the form but, rather, is in some other container, e.g. a `Panel`. That means that it is in the `Controls` collection of that container, not that of the form. You can also call the `Find` method of the form's `Controls` collection to search it and its children. Note that that will return a `Control` array, because there could be multiple controls with the same name in different containers.

Comment: Oh wow. Yes, it is in a Panel. Awesome. Thanks.

Comment: For reference, in my case this was the code that fixed it: `Dim lListH As ListBox = CType(Me.cSplitTop.Panel1.Controls(sControlName), ListBox)`

Comment: @LPChip, one point worth noting is that, if both `ListBoxes` will be in the same container then you could use `lList.Parent.Controls` and then it will work regardless of the specific configuration.

Comment: Oh thanks. I have more listboxes and this code is meant to be dynamic but every hidden clone of the listbox its pared to is in the same container and that broke my code, so I moved the hidden listboxes to all be in the same place, given they are going to be invisible anyway, but knowing this, I'm likely going to undo that. Thanks! :) I'd give you another +1 if I could. :)

Comment: @LPChip, why do you have hidden `ListBoxes` in the first place? It sounds like you're abusing UI controls to do something that should be done otherwise. Most likely you should be creating a single list of objects containing the data that you currently have in two `ListBoxes`. Selecting the displayed data in the one `ListBox` will then inherently select the associated data.

Comment: I have a visible listbox and whatever I do to that, I also do it to the hidden listbox but with altered content. If I use different controls, I fear that I am making things more complex. At first I created a virtual listbox but my code was not working then either, so during debugging I turned it into a normal listbox, and that actually helps me a great deal in the debugging as I can now see what's happening, and I'll just make it invisible at the end.

Comment: @LPChip, what do you mean by "do"? Are you just talking about selection? There's no way that you should be using hidden controls but exactly what you should do is unclear without knowing more. Like I said, you should almost certainly create a single list that contains the data from both current lists. You can then display only the visible aspect of it and then, when you select an item, you have direct access to the other data via that item.

Comment: I have a textfile where each row is loaded as item in the listbox in the form of a todo list. I allow manipulation of the list, such as reordering and moving items as well as loading an item in and placing it in a textbox and back. The first x chars of the list are variables to that todo item, and I basically got from a simple program to something more complex and I don't feel like rewriting everything from scratch because the project is not that big yet and its not going to get much more features either.